# How do I get system_profiler output from a lot of machines in a network?

Tags: terminal, applescript, script

I need to have a script that will execute "system_profiler -detailLevel full" command in a remote mac machine. While this is going on, the user on the remote machine should not know that there is something happening.

I tried the following applescript:

```
tell application "Terminal" of machine "eppc://<ip address of remote machine>"
    activate
    do script "system_profiler -detailLevel full >> /$HOSTNAME.txt" 
end tell
```

This activates the terminal app on the desktop and hence a bad idea, as user working on that remote machine is interrupted. I want this to happen in the background.

I want a shell script (not an applescript) that will take the name of hostnames from a text file stored on the same location where the shell script is. It will then go to each host from that list of hostnames, execute the system_profiler command and copy the text file having the output of the command ($HOSTNAME.txt file) back to the machine from where the shell script was executed.

The file copying should be done without ssh,scp etc.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `ssh`, `scp` etc? Might be difficult to access remote systems otherwise on shell level.

Comment: yes i understand. What i have come accross that there are commercial products like SAM tools, which gather data from remote mac systems without authentication prompts..Hence i want to do it with scripting. SSH.SCP would require authentication everytime i connect to a remote machine.

Comment: There is some kind of authentication/autorization required irregardless of the tools used (even for Applescript). `ssh` and friends won't require additional authentication once you've set up public/private key pairs for all connections required.

Answer (score 1):

For reading a text file of hostnames into an AppleScript list, see [Read textfile into list in Applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064849/read-textfile-into-list-in-applescript).

For looping over hostnames within your AppleScript list see [An AppleScript list iterate/loop example](http://alvinalexander.com/apple/applescript-list-iterate-items-for-loop-mac):

```
set myList to {"Hello", "Goodbye", "I must be going"}
repeat with theItem in myList
  say theItem
end repeat
```

### do shell script

To avoid launching **Terminal.app**, use the **do shell script** command:

```
tell machine "eppc://<ip address of remote machine>"
    do shell script "system_profiler -detailLevel full > /tmp/sysprofile.txt"
end tell
```

This can be run without launching a supporting graphical application.

I am assuming you can not access the remote host via secure shell, only via Remote AppleEvent access `eppc`.

### Returning the File

Read the contents of the file within your AppleScript's `tell machine` block and save it locally outside of the `tell machine` block.

Alternatively, have you considered transferring back the system profile file via `ssh` or `scp`? Consider having your AppleScript to connect to your Mac and copy back the collected system profile.